# Missing jar in maven repo

Tags: maven, maven-3

Library depends on library, which missing in maven central (error 404 [missing library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.media/jai_core/1.1.3)). I tired to download the same library from an external source and placed into local Maven Repository, but it's not working. How can I solve this problem?

```
The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.media:jai-core:jar:1.1.3, com.sun.media:jai-codec
:jar:1.1.3: Failure to find javax.media:jai-core:jar:1.1.3 in http://repo.maven.
apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be rea
ttempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

If I adds these libraries in pom of my project(just for testing local repo), it's ok (from local repo). Problem, that [another library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.intarsys.opensource/iscwt/5.5) depends on them.
My pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.intarsys.opensource</groupId> //lib in maven central
            <artifactId>jPodRenderer</artifactId>     //depends on libs below
            <version>5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.media</groupId>      //in local repo
            <artifactId>jai_core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.media</groupId>    //in local repo
            <artifactId>jai_codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the exact maven error you are getting. Try running with -X (Debug). Also, did you put the downloaded jar in the correct location according to the GAV declaration (eg. `com/java/public/<version>/<some-jar>.jar`)

Comment: What happen if u add de.intarsys.opensource to your Pom.xml? Did you added that into your pom?

Comment: where exactly add it?

Comment: The above is the current pom right? Now also it is showing the same error???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure that the version of jar file you download has the same version with the file in pom.xml.
Make sure that you put the jar file in the correct directory.

Comment: you specifically wrote poRN.xml?

Comment: jai_core jar is actually missing from maven central due to deployment bug.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just try it out.
I'm not sure I understood your question.

**Pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.media</groupId>    //in local repo
 <artifactId>jai_codec</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
 <artifactId>jai_core</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>de.intarsys.opensource</groupId>
 <artifactId>iscwt</artifactId>
 <version>5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: <dependency>
 <groupId>de.intarsys.opensource</groupId>
 <artifactId>iscwt</artifactId>
 <version>5.5</version>
</dependency>  Can u try and see this version

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution is to add a Maven repository in your project source code. See here for an example on how to add a library to a custom maven repository :

http://david-codes.blogspot.com/2014/03/maven-add-custom-repository-in-your.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference in the name: 
maven was searching for jar-core, but you refer to jai_core
The first one is available on https://repository.jboss.org/maven2, the second one on maven central https://repo1.maven.org/maven2

Comment: Yes this is working. Seems it is searching for jai-core and it is searching for  jai_core